# Google Places API - search by non-standard category/type

Tags: python, google-maps, google-places-api

I'm trying to build a script to collect a set of places in a given area that all have the same type category (homeless shelters). I'm currently using the `python-google-places` package, and can do a normal search if I know the name of a shelter and the city. At the same time, I can't specify "Homeless Shelter" as the type to retrieve a set of all places in a given geography.

When I search for the location in Google Maps, there is a sub-category labeled Homeless Shelters that I can click on to see a list of other places on the map (see the attached screenshot of the label that I'm talking about). At the same time, I can't specify "Homeless Shelter" as the type to retrieve a set of all places in a given geography. If I inspect the types for this specific example, it only lists the following as the returned types: "point_of_interest" and "establishment". Is there a way to filter the API search results to match this same label?

Example: https://ibb.co/MSFKtt8

Comment: Not all types are available through the API. If you believe this one should be, open a feature request.

Answer (score 0):

Currently, the place types as seen on Google Maps (like 'Homeless shelter' in your attached screenshot) is currently not supported on the Google Maps Platform - Places API.

There is an existing feature request on our Google Issue Tracker here to support these place types on the Places API. To express your interest and for you to subscribe for any updates on this request, I suggest that you star this [Google Issue Tracker entry](https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/35822953).

In the mean time, you may want to consider using other Places API Service such as the [Nearby Search](https://developers-dot-devsite-v2-prod.appspot.com/places/web-service/search#PlaceSearchRequests), or [Text Search](https://developers-dot-devsite-v2-prod.appspot.com/places/web-service/search#TextSearchRequests) service to get a list of places where the term "Homeless shelter" is matched. *Although this will not guarantee that you will get the exact same search result as a Google Map search since the Google Maps Platform products is a separate product from the Google Maps consumer app (maps.google.com).*

Here's a sample request using the `python-google-places` package:

***Using Text Search***

```
from googleplaces import GooglePlaces

YOUR_API_KEY = 'YOUR_API_KEY'

google_places = GooglePlaces(YOUR_API_KEY)

query_result = google_places.text_search(
  lat_lng = {'lat': 40.740614, 'lng': -73.976601}, 
  query='homeless shelters',
  radius=5000
)

for place in query_result.places:
  print(place.name)
```

***Using Nearby Search***

```
from googleplaces import GooglePlaces

YOUR_API_KEY = 'YOUR_API_KEY'

google_places = GooglePlaces(YOUR_API_KEY)

query_result = google_places.nearby_search(
  lat_lng = {'lat': 40.740614, 'lng': -73.976601}, 
  keyword='homeless shelters',
  radius=5000
)

for place in query_result.places:
  print(place.name)
```

> Note that we also have an [official Client Libraries for Google Maps
>   Web Services](https://developers.google.com/places/web-service/client-library). Here's the specific library for Python:
>   https://github.com/googlemaps/google-maps-services-python